# Accessing Data of Linked Objects by a Property Chain in a Single Variable

Tags: powershell, object, properties

I am trying to access data of two linked objects by using the chain of the relevant properties. However, the chain of properties is only available in a single variable and that seems to bother Powershell.

Here is an example:

```
$DeliveryNote = New-Object System.Object
$DeliveryNote | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ID -Value "DN-2017-005"

$ObjLetters = New-Object System.Object
$ObjLetters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DeliveryNote -Value $DeliveryNote

$DeliveryNote = "DeliveryNote"
$ID = "ID"
$PropChain ="DeliveryNote.ID"

$ObjLetters.$DeliveryNote.$ID            # works fine
$ObjLetters."$($DeliveryNote)"."$($ID)"  # works fine

$ObjLetters.$PropChain                   # does not work
$ObjLetters."$($PropChain)"              # does not work
```

Accessing the final data "DN-2017-005" works fine as long as the properties are available as single variables. But as soon as both properties are in a single variable I get no result as output.
Does anybody has an idea how to handle the properties in a single variable?

Comment: See [Problems parsing / accessing nested JSON / Hashtable data via variables in Powershell](//stackoverflow.com/a/41878478)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interesting hint. Based on the hash table information I solved my issue with the following code:

```
Function Get-DeepObjectProperty {
    Param(
    [object] $QualifiedObjectProperty,
    [string] $PropertyChain)

    $PropertyArray = $PropertyChain.split("\.")
    $PropertyArray | ForEach-Object {$QualifiedObjectProperty = $QualifiedObjectProperty.$_}

    $QualifiedObjectProperty
}

...

Get-DeepObjectProperty $ObjManualSet $PropertyChain = $DataContent
```